# Win (dualboot) - reboot to specific version

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, bootloader

I have Windows 10 on HDD1 and Windows 7 on HDD2. After PC start, I can choose which system I want to boot into (it is a native bootloader, it was installed automatically during W10 installation). W10 is intended to be personal, W7 is my working system (joined to company domain etc.)

The problem is that it takes really long time to show up this bootloader and **I usually restart** the system to **boot to the other** system.

So, is it possible to somehow **preselect** version and then **reboot** system, so all this OS selection thing will be **skipped**, thus system startup **much faster**?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool like [BootNext](https://www.boyans.net/bootnext/bootnext.html).

Alternatively you can create two scripts - one for direct boot of Windows 7, another for direct boot of Windows 10.

You could have only one script - for direct booting the non-default OS!
(assuming Windows 10 is default, Windows 7 is alternative)

The scripts would contain one single command:

bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootnext {GUID_of_OS_to_be_booted}

bootnext element sets one time boot GUID relevant for next reboot and skips default OS preload (preload was introduced for faster boot of default OS).

bcdedit needs admin rights.